# Regex group match if present

Tags: ruby, regex

My input string is:

```
/234243/source_path/a/b/c.test
```

or something like:

```
/234243/source_path/a/b/c.test/check_w123
```

I want a regex to match substrings starting with `source` and `check` with the result like:

- `source`: `source_path/a/b/c.test/`
- `check`: `check_w123`

using a regex like `/(?<source>source.*)(?<check>check.*)/` without `?` in the last group.

My regex is:

```
/(?<source>source.*)(?<check>check.*)?/
```

My Result is:

- `source`: `source_path/a/b/c.test/check_w123`
- `check`: `nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn `.*` inside the first source group into it's non-greedy form. And don't forget to add end of the line anchor.

```
(?<source>source.*?)(?<check>check.*)?$
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/r7vp1Y0Hqq)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<source>source.*?(?!.*\/))(?<check>check.*)?
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/11